# Error on Nginx when trying to configure it as a Web Server and reverse proxy for Apache on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, nginx

I got both the Apache and Nginx servers working fine until I ran:

> sudo certbot --nginx -d myhost.com -d www.myhost.com

and restarted Nginx.

Looking at the logs I get the error:

> nginx: [crit] pread() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mod_rpaf-stable"
>   failed (21: Is a directory)

Is it a permissions issue like www-data or a problem with mod_rpaf-stable?
I tried to find information online but I'm getting nowhere.

Comment: Exact duplicate of https://superuser.com/q/1479880/302907

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx error: \[crit\] pread() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mod\_rpaf-stable" failed (21: Is a directory)](https://superuser.com/questions/1479880/nginx-error-crit-pread-etc-nginx-sites-enabled-mod-rpaf-stable-failed-2)