# Nginx error: [crit] pread() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mod_rpaf-stable" failed (21: Is a directory)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I got both the Apache and Nginx servers working fine until I ran:

> sudo certbot --nginx -d myhost.com -d www.myhost.com

and restarted Nginx.

I got the error

> nginx: [crit] pread() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mod_rpaf-stable"
>   failed (21: Is a directory)

Is it a permissions issue , or a problem with mod_rpaf-stable?
I tried to find information online but I'm getting nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've erroneously placed `mod_rpaf-stable` to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`. The latter expects NGINX configuration files with `.conf` extension, named after domain names of websites you intend to host on your server.

The `mod_rpaf` belongs to the Apache world, and it has nothing to do with NGINX. Remove it or move out outside NGINX configuration directory.